# Scala Isomorphic Types

Tags: scala, isomorphism

Reading this blog [post](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/) from Chuusai, it says:

```
def size(x : Either[Int, String]) = x match {
  case Left(i) => i
  case Right(s) => s.length
}

size(Left(23)) == 23    // OK
size(Right("foo")) == 3 // OK
```

> Either[Int, String] can model the union type Int ∨ String because
>   there is an isomorphism between the two types and their values

What's "there is an isomorphism between the two types and their values" mean?

Comment: You are mean "Curry-Howard isomorphism" and good explanation here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/The_Curry-Howard_isomorphism

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define the term "values" in the context of Scala.  I'm assuming that means canonical expressions with that type, expressions of the form Left(*n*) or Right(*s*) for constant integer *n* or string *s*.  Then the isomorphism is a straightforward mapping onto the mathematical type Int ∪ String.  But what about, e.g., null, or Right( null )?  Do these have images under this mapping?  Doesn't seem totally isomorphic to me.